# Counter variable gets reset to 0 without resetting it(Mega)

Tags: arduino-mega

(Arduino Mega2560) I'm trying to test placing a counter n in a for loop, the problem is, every time it gets out and goes back to the for loop, the n is reset again, so it prints "counter: 245" every time. However, when I comment out *b++=data; and data++; it does count properly. What exactly is going on ?!

Code:

```
uint8_t i=0;
uint8_t buf[245];
uint8_t *b=buf,*b2=buf;
uint8_t data=10;
int n=0;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {  
for(i=0; i<245 ;i++){
  *b++=data;
  data++; 
  delay(50);
  n++;
  Serial.println(buf[i]);
  }
  data=0;
  delay(5000);
  Serial.println("counter:");
  Serial.println(n); 
  delay(5000);
}
```

Comment: `b` is heading off into the unknown and you're blasting all your other variables with junk.

Comment: Oh I see ! I have never tried pointers before, can I do b=0 to reset it or it's done a different way ?

Comment: `b = buf;` will reset `b` to the start of the `buf` variable memory area. Your `b++` goes up and up and up otherwise with no limit. After 254 increments it will be pointing at something *after* `buf` - which sounds like `n` to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never reset your `b` pointer. The first time through it works its way through the memory reserved for `buf`. The second time through your loop it's already at the end of that memory and you then start incrementing (and filling) past that overwriting other variables - the first of which sounds like it might be `n` - so `*b++=data` is writing `data` (245) to `n`.

You need to reset `b` each time you go through loop so it starts at the beginning of the array each time:

```
b = buf;
```

Comment: Thanks Majenko, it makes sense now.

Comment: @Majenko ... upvoted ... my mistake indeed.